# Ubuntu, Node.js, sqlcmd, sqlcmd-runner component: work locally (windows 10), restart (pm2) app.js on Ubuntu server, Why?

Tags: server, scripts, nodejs, mssql

I code backend in Windows 10, vs-code, and upload code to Ubuntu server, node.js, MsSQL express.
In my case, I need to make a new database for every customer, then dynamically create a database ( no problem here) after that I have to run a copy of script to build schemas, types, functions (this is first script), then if successful I have to run script to create tables (second script), and if successes I run the third script file for all stored procedures, then the database is ready for use.

**To run script files, I depend on `sqlcmd-runner`, here is the code we use:**

```
var sqlcmd = require('sqlcmd-runner');

exports.executeFile = (year, file_data, fileErr, cb) => {
    sqlcmd({
        username: 'sa',
        password: 'Roshan1402Roshan',
        server: 'localhost',
        database: 'ebrahimi_522_1402',
        port: 1433,
        trustServerCert: true,
        inputFiles: [`${file_data}`],
        outputFile: `${fileErr}`,
    })
    .catch((error) => { 
        cb(error.message)
    })
    .done((data) => { 
        cb(null, data)
    }); }
```

In our developing environment (Windows 10, MSSQL, Nodejs etc. are installed ) every steps works properly, and job finishes well.

I searched and it seems that to run `sqlcmd` I had to setup it, I followed all steps to setup `sqlcmd` on my `ubuntu` server.
To check if `sqlcmd` is working I tried this code and it works well:
**This create all schemas and others:**

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d db_roshan_ir -U sa -P Roshan1402Roshan -C -i "/var/www/hesabroshan/app.hesabroshan.ir/Scripts/001/functions.sql"
```

**This creates all tables:**

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d db_roshan_ir -U sa -P Roshan1402Roshan -C -i "/var/www/hesabroshan/app.hesabroshan.ir/Scripts/001/tables.sql"
```

**And this creates all stored procedures:**

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d db_roshan_ir -U sa -P Roshan1402Roshan -C -i "/var/www/hesabroshan/app.hesabroshan.ir/Scripts/001/sps.sql"
```

**But when we run our project using pm2 and monitor it this error happens:**

```
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn sqlcmd',
path: 'sqlcmd',
spawnargs: [
    '-S',
    'localhost', 
    '-d',
    'db_roshan_ir',
    '-U',
    'sa',
    '-P',
    'Roshan1402Roshan',
    '-C',
    '-i',
    '\\var\\www\\hesabroshan\\app.hesabroshan.ir\\Scripts\\001\\functions.sql',
    '-o',
    '\\var\\www\\hesabroshan\\app.hesabroshan.ir\\Scripts\\001\\err_func_522_14'
]
```

I believe that there is a problem yet with the server, but I can not find it out.
I have tried many ways, many server addresses like Ip, Ip+instance, Ip+instance+port.